# Error: Unable to access jarfile Click-The-Block.jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

I have made a simple game that I want to convert into a runnable jar so I can show others and launch it without Eclipse.

In Eclipse I:

1. Right clicked on Project
2. Export
3. Java > Exectuable Jar File
4. Launch Configuration: CTB (1) - Click The Block

It made a jar with a MANIFEST.MF containing:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0  
Class-Path: .  
Main-Class: uk.co.robertmerriman.ctb.main.CTB
```

This was all extracted to my desktop in Click-The-Block.jar

When I double click, nothing happens.
When I type "java -jar Click-The-Block.jar" into CMD, I get the following error:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile Click-The-Block.jar.
```

Answer (score 2):

**Make your jar file name without spaces locally, then write in cmd like the following:**

```
java -jar YourjarFileNameWithoutSpaces.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an OS issue. If you are running windows 07 or vista try running the same in administrator mode. 
Also make sure that when you are running the command

> java -jar Click-The-Block.jar

You are running it from the directory where the jar is located.

Comment: Nope, this hasn't worked... I'm in the right dir, run as administrator, navigated manually to dir; nothing.

Comment: Should I try re-installing java? Should my CLASSPATH have a value?

Comment: Can you try after removing the Class-Path: . entry from MANIFEST.MF

Comment: try giving absolute path to both java.exex and your jar file

Answer (score 0):

if your java.exe is in c:\java\bin\java.exe and your Click-The-Block.jar is in c:\dev\
Then try out the following command

>
c:\java\bin\java -jar c:\dev\Click-The-Block.jar

Also try renaming your jar file with no cps letter, i know this will not have any effect but there's no harm in trying.

If you are still not able to execute the jar then try downloading an executable jar file from the net and see if you are able to run it using the standard java command. If you still get the same error which means the problem is not with your jar but somthing to do with how java is configured in the system. In that case you can go ahead and reinstall a fresh jdk and try al over again.

Hope it helps ...

Comment: Nope nothing. Have done all that, other jars seem to work and a fresh JDK isn't. Should I try exporting it with Eclipse Indigo and not Juno?

Comment: if it works with other jars, the problem is in your jar. Try starting with a simple program, which contains only one class and a mian method, and try exporting it  , see if it works. if it works just copy all you click block classes into the new project and do the same. then change the main file and export it again ...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my executable jar generated by maven-shade-plugin "DCD-Desktop-1.0.jar" , I removed the dashes and renamed it to "dcd.jar" and it worked fine .